# If I have around 3000 variables in a spark dataframe, how do I create 3 dataframes of 1000 variables each

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a big dataframe of 3000 variables. I would like to divide this into 3 dataframes of 1000,1000,1000 variables in each of them. 
What I have tried so far is to make 3 lists of 1000,1000 and 1000 variable names. But I don't know how to select just those 1000 variables using the list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `df.select()` as below:

```
first_df = df.select(df.columns[:1000])
second_df = df.select(df.columns[1000:2000])
third_df = df.select(df.columns[2000:3000])
```

Hope that helps :)